# slow loading horizontal progressbar

Tags: android, progress-bar

I would like my progress bar to load slowly from left to right, but it immediately displays in the view, after start activity.

```java
public class adapterholder{
    int categories;
    int finishedCategories;

    progressbar.setMax(categories);
    progressbar.setProgress(finishedCategories)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to add `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);` before `the progressbar.setMax(categories)` line of code.

> instead of **seconds** you will put a time value in **seconds**, that your programm will wait before running the code after it.

Hope this helps.